# getting runtime error for EF4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IRepository<Group> groupRepo = new Repository<Group>();

            var k = groupRepo.GetAll().ToList();

            return View("Groups");
        }
```

using simple `GetAll()` i'm trying to get all data from table

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public Repository()
        { 
            DbContext dbContext = new MusicoDatabaseContext();
            if (dbContext == null) 
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Null DbContext");
            DbContext = dbContext;
            DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
        }

          protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

        protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }
```

But still i'm getting runtime error:

```
An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.
```

Comment: And a couple of other dupes: https://www.google.com/#q=An+error+occurred+while+getting+provider+information+from+the+database.+This+can+be+caused+by+Entity+Framework+using+an+incorrect+connection+string.+Check+the+inner+exceptions+for+details+and+ensure+that+the+connection+string+is+correct.  Incredible!!! Do people even search before posting a question on StackOverflow? Sometimes I feel that when someone gets an exception in Visual Studio, he simply copy-pastes it into a SO question. You know, copy-pasting it in Google usually will get you faster responses. Sorry for being rude.

Comment: ofcourse yes google is the best but most of the time it is not giving the proper explanation what SO gives :P

Comment: Dude, google is just the tool that you use to get to the SO answers (which you qualified as answers giving proper explanation). Did you click on my google link in the previous comment? Did you notice the search query I used? Did you notice that it is the error message you got? Did you notice that the first 4 results were from SO? Did you click on those results? I mean, dude, c'mon.

Comment: that was really useful thanks one question i'm using class library project for EF4 is it necessary to install EF4 in my WebUI project or reference is fine?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could have all your DAL stuff in a separate class library. Then you will reference this class library in your MVC application. So implicitly the EF will be referenced. And in your web.config you will be able to define the proper connection string. Yes, in the web.config of your MVC application. There's no such notion as config file for a class library. If you placed your connection string inside the App.config of your class library you can totally forget about it. You shouldn't even have an App.config for a class library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have incorrect connection string. Btw, connection strings are little bit complicated with EF, so here is one which works for me (add it to web.config before closing `configuration` tag):

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=my_project_db;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;LANGUAGE=English" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>

    <!-- set up migrations -->
    <contexts>
      <context type="MyProject.MyProjectContext, MyProject">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[MyProject.MyProjectContext,                      MyProject], [MyProject.Migrations.Configuration, MyProject]], EntityFramework" />
      </context>
    </contexts>

    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```